# Multi Applications as Docker Containers in a Cluster, Ways to Handle MySQL

Tags: mysql, docker, containers, kubernetes

Most of the articles online regarding setting up Docker containers seem to be written around the idea of breaking an application into microservices and allocating them into various containers and deploying them into a cluster.

I would like to find out the best way to handle databases (e.g. MySQL) for multiple unrelated applications, written for different clients, and deployed into the same cluster.

Say I have 10 unrelated small applications (like WordPress), all requiring access to MySQL database. I could:

1. Deploy the applications as containers into the cluster, containing just the application code, and setting up a dedicated MySQL server or a Google Cloud SQL instance and asking each of the application containers to connect to the database as 3rd party services.
2. Deploy the applications as containers into the cluster. For each applications, also deploy a separate database container into the cluster and link the two.
3. Deploy a separate database container into the cluster and link this container to the various application containers in the cluster.

Which of these solutions is the best in terms of application architecture design and which of these is the best use of computer resources? I have the feeling that deploying multiple MySQL containers (one for each application) may be the best design but it might not be the most resource-efficient as we will have a bunch of MySQL containers running.

Comment: Well... what do you favor more? Having a single MySQL database to manage or separating them out for each application? There are probably other question that could be asked to help sway the decision as well. Like, are each of the applications separate clients where there could be a concern of shared resources? Are you comfortable with managing MySQL and the persistent data as a container? This is also tagged as Kubernetes. In the case where an application might run on multiple hosts, how would you handle persistent database data scheduling should the database start on another host?

Comment: @AndyShinn I am looking to implement it in Kubernetes. In Kubernetes, there are a few persistent storage options. What I am interested in is compare the performance of running databases from a dedicated server as service against setting up each of the db as a container. Right now, I think it would be easier to run mysql as a separate service and let my application codes to be read only containers. Containerising db for each app seems to be "the docker way" and provide better isolation and portability... but performance-wise which way is more efficient?

Comment: Performance-wise, I don't think there is any difference between running on the host or in a container. The overhead of a container is negligible. However, performance of a container versus a dedicated service such as Cloud SQL will definitely be differently and should be compared. But as you pointed out, a service like Cloud SQL may certainly be easier, and have other advantages such as scaling and high availability (which will take a lot of your own architecting to get working as containers).

Comment: @AndyShinn while the performance of 1 db container vs a db process running in host might be similar, I am interested to find out how it will perform if we have 20 db containers (which running its own db process) vs 1 db process running on host supporting 20 dbs.

Answer (score 3):

> Containerising db for each app seems to be "the docker way" and provide better isolation and portability

The docker way isn't a db per app but a service per container. 
MySQL is a service at soon as you don't run in the mysql container an another service (app/ssh/monitoring...) it's the way to go.

**So the decision between one db per app or one db for all  is up to you.**

My personal choice is the third:

> 3. Deploy a separate database container into the cluster and link this container to the various application containers in the cluster.

I'm using kubernetes with a postgres container that is used as a DB server for all applications.

I prefer this choice because it's easier as an OP point of view to backup/replicate/apply maintenance than having 30 differents db servers + 30*slaves + 30*external pool + 30*monitoring tools etc... 
Also in my case I have a better hw resources usage.

But I conserve the possibility to move a database to another dedicated db-server container in case an application is using too much resource or if too many app are already using the DB.

Comment: While I would tend to agree, your answer still follows a sort of "depends on your environment" point of view. I could also see the opposite being true if those 30 applications (all using their own database) were managed by different teams and it was up to the teams to handle updates, migrations, and changes to the database. If there a problems with that database (during and upgrade, backup, or user error), then it wouldn't affect all 30 applications. It would essentially be part of the Pod and only be concern to that particular Pod.